# Непонятен фрагмент кода javascript

Tags: javascript

Делаю парсер avito, все отлично но не понимаю я код js немного.
В каждой странице сайта есть такая штука как номер телефона, как его получить я знаю если кому надо расскажу.
как сгенерировать pkey я тоже нашел привожу пример:

```
item_phone = '06659534cbb5k03c5b7818e76kc0b01e2f9b3133f2b30a76c9d9cb7ab3bk7f3413e9f2e1k9b0367e8187b2c355b3c4e59666';
item_id = 113432709;

function phoneDemixer(key){
        var pre = key.match(/[0-9a-f]+/g),mixed=(item_id%2===0?pre.reverse():pre).join(''),s=mixed.length,r='',k;
        for(k=0;k<s;++k){
          if(k%3===0){r+=mixed.substring(k,k+1);
        }
        }
       return r;
    }
alert( phoneDemixer(item_phone) );
```

В общем вопрос вот этот pre что это за запятые как из mixed получается из key получить зачем этот for я так понимаю что он каждый третий элемент выбирает. Меня интересует pre, что оно таким кодом генерирует.

Comment: хотя-бы помогите этот pre по другому более понятно рассписать, в общем чтобы вопрос не казался совсем глупым я понимаю что в var pre генерируется последовательность перове фильрует item_phone второе обращает эту самую последовательность наоборот если item_id делится на 2 т.е. парное. join объеденяет эти самые последоваельности только не понимаю какую именно, дальше вообше присваивание к чему бы это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось достаточно банально:

1. key.match(...) сделало массив.
2. проверило парность ид если парно перевернуло массив и првело его обратно к строке.
3. посчитало длину 2
4. просто какое-то присваивание как и 5 в принципе.

т.е. на 3 мы получили длину строки на 2 строку.
потом прошли по строке и выбрали каждый третий элемент.